# How to Convert Datetime Picker value to Datetime in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, datetimepicker

i have datepicker in UI i want to convert datepicker value to time in ruby on rails but it reverse the month and date that is the reason i have an issue please help me to solve this issue

example 
   params[:select_date] having the value `04/12/2013` if it converted into time as follows it shows as follows

```
 params[:select_date].to_time it gives value as 2013-12-04 00:00:00 UTC
```

date and month is interchanged please help to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params[:select_date].to_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Please read the documention on [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime).

Comment: it gives the error for date like 04/23/2013 it didn't covert.

Comment: That is an invalid date, thus you must explicitly tell the parser its format. Example: `Date.strptime("04/23/2013", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: in my scenario using @t i will pass date value in above format,as you said i write as follows but again it shows same error         <%= Date.strptime(@t, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>

Comment: `irb(main):011:0> Date.strptime("04/23/2013", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

`=> "23/04/2013"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Date.strptime(params[:select_date], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

I tried the above code and it is working fine.

my input was 06/08/2015 (mm/dd/Y) I got the result like 2015/06/08 00:00:00

I hope it will help you.

Happy coding :)